# How to build java agent from source and static load in tomee application by maven?

Tags: java, maven

We are using java agent to customize some runtime initialization steps, it works by manually build the java agent and include the jar in JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh. As it's not good to add jar into code repository, we expect build both java agent and our web application by maven, besides inject the java agent in the application as described above. How could we achieve it by maven? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In one pom.xml, We used maven-war-plugin to build application war and maven-assembly-plugin to build java agent fat jar:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <id>agent</id>
  <formats>
      <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
          <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
          <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
          <includes>
            <include>package/**</include>
          </includes>
      </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
      <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <includes>
        <include>org.json:json</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```